# How do i build the packaging type CBA in pom.xml for java-maven project

Tags: maven, websphere

My project is in structure of java-maven. Need to package as CBA and move into artifactory

Comment: What is CBA? Could you give a short explanation?

Comment: It s a Composite Bundle Archive. CBA is an archive file with a .cba file extension. It contains a composite manifest META-INF/COMPOSITEBUNDLE.MF which defines the CBA and optionally some OSGi bundles with which to seed the repository.Need to deploy into .CBA package type into artifactory